# Python TTS Modules for Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: python, text-to-speech, raspberry-pi4

Ok so earlier this month I managed to figure out how to download modules for my Raspberry Pi (thank you to everyone that helped out on that) but now I've ran into another problem. I can't seem to find any TTS module that will actually produce speech. If anyone can suggest a python module and how I can use it that would be great thanks :).

Comment: Full disclosure I work for them, but the CereProc SDK is compatible with Raspberry Pi

Comment: @dabhand thanks for replying I'll be checking it out soon.